# 409 status return from the server

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

I'm getting '409 status' when I call web request. Does it occur that because my code is wrong or is it a web service error?

Below is my code. What I  was trying to do was to Get response from payload request.

```
Random random = new Random();
    URL url = new URL("https://biz.mobizz.lk/apicall/prepaidloan/afc");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer f74e85137735aa937492hdasd1");
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    osw.write(String.format("{\"mobile\":\"72131185\",\"method\":\"SMS\",\"loanAmount\":\"200000\"}"));
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
    System.err.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
```

Comment: Isn´t the `Authorization` part randomly generated? That could generate the 409. Which is a conflict error.

Comment: @Neijwiert Authorization part is not randomly generated, it is a given static token we need to send for authorization.